# Want to communicate between pods in same cluster but different namespace in GKE 1.16.10-gke.8

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I have multiple database in one of the namespace named database in GKE & trying to connect to database namespace from service namespace pods. Database connection fails in the microservices in service namespace. If I move the same microservice pod to database namespace , things work on connection. Not sure what Network issue, between namespaces in same cluster.

I am able to ping all the pods in database namespace from service namespace, but connection fails, mainly I see socket connection based database connection pool fails to connect. Any help here will be great.

This started happening after upgrading to latest GKE K8s version - 1.16.10-gke.8 from 1.15.*

I even added network policy to allow all ingress in database namespace.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: order
  namespace: devservice
  labels:
    app: order
spec:
  ports:
    - port: 3000
      name: http
  selector:
    app: order
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: order-v1
  namespace: devservice
  labels:
    app: order
    version: v1
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: order
      version: v1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: order
        version: v1
    spec:
      nodeSelector:
        cloud.google.com/gke-nodepool: pool-b
      containers:
        - name: order
          image: docker/imageforservertorunnodeservices
          imagePullPolicy: Always
          ports:
            - containerPort: 3000
      initContainers:
        - name: install
          image: docker/imagefornodenpm
      volumes:
        - name: workdir
          emptyDir: {}
      imagePullSecrets:
        - name: prod-key
---
```

Comment: add yamls of netpol,service,pod

Comment: there is no issue with service, or pod. If I exec bash and get into the pod and try ping to the db url from terminal -> service-name.namespace.svc.cluster.local it works. But connection to databases like elastic & cassandra fails, but connection to databases like rethink & redis works. Same pod moved to database namespace , everything connects & works. I feel issue with network. Any specific commands u suggest to get traffic reads. Because, netstat, telnet, ping nothing helped so far...

Comment: Even created a fresh GKE cluster, same issue with recent versions of kubernetes. Something restricted in recent times, is what I feel  on networking, which blocks the sustained connection pool of dbs

Comment: If you post your yamls we can try to replicate the behavior and help troubleshoot forward. Reserve some time to read [**how to create a minimal, reproducible example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Providing the necessary details, including warnings, errors, and details to reproduce your scenario will not only help you, but enable you to help others with similar issues!

Comment: have added the yaml, i dont think this yaml can help you find the problem. this works on same namespace, i have db in devdb namespace, if I change the above order service to map to devdb instead of devservice namespace, things work on maintaining connections to database.

Comment: is it the problem only with databases? If you try to run a simple server on a pod namespace and connect to it from another namespace - is it the problem as well?